# Add a Reference Via F#'s Interactive Window

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

Is it possible to add a reference to a .NET library via F#'s interactive window?  For example:

```
> open System.Xml.Linq;;

  open System.Xml.Linq;;
  ----------------^^^^

stdin(2,17): error FS0039: The namespace 'Linq' is not defined.
>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
> #r "System.Xml.Linq" ;;
```

Comment: The problem is that the interactive window does not share the references of the VS project, so you have to manually import the dll.  This is also true of fsx files.

Answer (score 0):

For the people looking to import a non .NET reference. You can do that with:

```ml
#r "./path/to/my.dll"
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33578752/6329629).